# Javascript using requestAnimationFrame on scroll event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem when using `window.requestAnimationFrame` on a `scroll` event.

I want to move a `DIV` using `CSS transform:translate3D`.

```
document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("scroll", function(){

var getScroll = this.scrollTop * 1.2;

function repeatOften() {

    document.getElementById("moveable").style.transform = 
        "translate3D(0," + getScroll + "px, 0)";
    requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);

}

requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften); 

});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tcayv8dp/

Why is this animation not running smoothly? What is wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The animation seems smooth to me.

However, you shouldn't be calling `requestAnimationFrame` inside the function as those calls will keep running endlessly.

This is how I would improve your code:

```
// define the function outside the onscroll function so it doesn't get redefined
var getScroll;
function repeatOften() {
    // use translateY instead of translate3D
    document.getElementById("moveable").style.transform = "translateY(" + getScroll + "px)";
};

document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("scroll", function(){

    getScroll = this.scrollTop * 1.2;
    requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);

});
```